# Need help on table design with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a simple web application where a doctor is adding multiple prescription records for patients and will select multiple drugs while doing prescription. So one patient has multiple prescription and one prescription has multiple selected drugs. I have taken one another table patientrecords for reporting purpose/Normalization perspective where I am referencing patientID and PrescriptionID.

- One patient --> many prescriptions --> one to many relationship
- One prescriptions -> many drugs --> one to many relationship

Below is the model for patient, prescription and drugs, `PatientRecord` table.

[image: PatientModel]

[image: DrugModel]

[image: PrescriptionModel]

[image: PatientRecordModel]

While running migration, I get this error:

> Error Number:1769,State:1,Class:16
>   Foreign key 'FK_Drugs_Prescriptions_PrescriptionID' references invalid column 'PrescriptionID' in referencing table 'Drugs'.

I am confused with explanation of one to many relationships on Microsoft website.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: are you migrating new database (or added relationship in an existing table)?

Comment: You should post your code **as nicely formatted text** - not as screenshots - this is rather annoying ....

Comment: @PankajRawat I am adding new tables to existing database

Comment: @PankajRawat I have already performed CRUD on my Patient and Drugs Table

Comment: @marc_s pardon me...next time...i will make sure to post question in formatted text

Comment: PrescriptionID or PrescriptionId? The error reports about PrescriptionID, but the Drug class declares PrescriptionId. There is no homogeneity in names: I see "id", "PatientId", "PrescriptionId", "PatientRecordID".. and other  properties whose names are lowercase, and the IDE is warning about them. Is it possible that the issue is caused by case sensitivity options in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to configure [the relationships in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

- Conventions :By default, a relationship will be created when there is a navigation property discovered on a type. **Not applicable to many-to-many relationship**
- Fluent API:you start by identifying the navigation properties that make up the relationship. `HasOne` or `HasMany` identifies the navigation property on the entity type you are beginning the configuration on.  `HasOne/WithOne` are used for reference navigation properties and `HasMany/WithMany` are used for collection navigation properties.

From your screenshots and the benjamin suggested, you could configure the model like below

Patient - Prescription --> one to many relationship
Prescription - Drug --> many to many relationship

```
public class Prescription
{
    public int PrescriptionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime PrescriptionDate { get; set; }

    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DrugPrescription> DrugPrescriptions { get; set; }
}
public class Drug
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CurrentStock { get; set; }
    public int DrugCost { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DrugPrescription> DrugPrescriptions { get; set; }
}

//represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for 
//the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.
 public class DrugPrescription
{
    public int DrugId { get; set; }
    public Drug Drug { get; set; }

    public int PrescriptionId { get; set; }
    public Prescription Prescription { get; set; }
}


//DbContext
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<Patient> Patient { get;set; }
    public DbSet<Drug> Drug { get;set; }
    public DbSet<Prescription> Prescription { get;set; }

    public DbSet<PatientRecord> PatientRecord { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        #region Drug-Prescription Many-to-Many
        builder.Entity<DrugPrescription>()
            .HasKey(dp => new { dp.DrugId, dp.PrescriptionId });

        builder.Entity<DrugPrescription>()
            .HasOne(dp => dp.Prescription)
            .WithMany(p => p.DrugPrescriptions)
            .HasForeignKey(dp => dp.PrescriptionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<DrugPrescription>()
            .HasOne(dp => dp.Drug)
            .WithMany(d => d.DrugPrescriptions)
            .HasForeignKey(dp => dp.DrugId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi...thank you for the explanation...I aleady added my patiet table to Database earlier..will it cause problem while doing this new migration

Comment: Hey...Thank you so much..it works for me..God Bless U

Comment: Glad to help you resolve the issue , could you mark my reply as answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that don't quite look right here. Maybe if you clean them up you'll be close to spotting where the error is.

Firstly, I'm a bit confused by your `PatientRecord` class. It identifies itself with a `PatientRecordId` and it maps to a `Patient`, but it doesn't add any other information, so what is it for? If you're not going to add anything to that class, I think you can remove it from the model.

Secondly, your `Prescription` class maps to a collection of `Drugs`. That's perfect because you have a one-to-many relationship between them... so why does it also have an integer `DrugId` property? Unless you want the `Prescription` class to reference the `Id` of one single `Drug` as well as the collection of `Drugs`, I think you should remove it. It might be confusing Entity Framework and not giving you any value.

Thirdly, your `Drug` class maps to one `Prescription` (through its properties `Prescription` and `PrescriptionId`) but why? Presumably a drug can appear on multiple prescriptions, as it could be prescribed to many people, or prescribed to the same person several times. So I think you want to remove that too and replace it with a many-to-many relationship.

Finally, if you want to have a many-to-many relationship between `Prescription` and `Drug` (and I think you will) you probably need to add a `DrugPrescription` class, with a `Drug` property and a `Prescription` property, to create this many-to-many mapping.

I think if you do that you'll be a lot close to your goal, and your error message will probably go away.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Benjamin...God bless you

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved your problem, please mark my response as the answer. If not, let me know and I'll try to help you some more.